# Push all stack in c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli, cpu-registers

I have a function in a c++/cli dll which is called by an old 1990s application. I'm using `#pragma managed(push, off)` before the function and `#pragma managed(pop)` after to preserve the stack but only EBP is push/pop. Because of that the application gives an error (some registers is invalid). I fixed it once by manually changing the dll file and adding the necessary push/pop to other registers, which fixed the problem, but it's silly to do that every time I change something. How can I force it to push/pop more than just EBP? I thought of using __asm { } but I'm not sure it will work..?

Comment: Using inline __asm is fine, a program from the 1990s isn't going to run 64-bit code.  The only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a mismatched calling convention?

Comment: You seem under the impression that `#pragma managed`'s `push` and `pop` options involve pushing or popping registers at execution time. They don't. They involve pushing/popping a compile-time variable within a stack internal to the compiler.

Comment: @Medinoc If that's the case then yes, I have misunderstood. I have searched quite a bit about `pragma managed` but I haven't found much details.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I can have the wrong calling convention. My dll is replacing an old dll and I don't have the source code for either the application or the old dll. I've created my replacement dll by debugging using Ollydbg and IdaPro as best as I can. I know the application is written in Borland in the 1990s so it's possible I should have used fastcall (Borland's version) but that's not valid in c++/cli I think. I've tried with stdcall but that mangles the exported function name.

Comment: Fastcall is not supported in the CLR P/Invoke according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx), but it should be supported in C++/CLI interop code, you may want to give it a try to figure it out. Try to stick `__fastcall` in the declaration.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Fastcall isn't supported, I got the following error: `warning C4561: '__fastcall' incompatible with the '/clr' option: converting to '__stdcall'`. But stdcall did the job! I guess stdcall is lot closer to fastcall than cdecl (caller/callee wise). Combined with a module definition file to get rid of the function name mangling (didn't think of that before) the application started without any error messages.

Comment: Aw, that sucks, they could at least leave `__fastcall` for native code and enforce it to also be called only from native code. And yes, fastcall is much closer to stdcall (the callee pops the args) than to cdecl (the caller pops the args). The only difference with stdcall is that a couple args are passed in the CPU registers instead of the stack. Anyway I'm glad you found a solution.